# How to convert java object into C struct

Tags: java, c

How I can convert Java Object into C struct? I know that I can translate the data with XML but I need more quick and easy way to do this? What are the possible solutions?

Comment: How is the Java Object presented to you? Is its data written into a file, do you have a pointer to an object, or is there some other way? This doesn't sound like you are just using a text editor. It would be nice if you edited your post and added information like that along with some code. Just a suggestion.

Comment: please elaborate a little, hopefully with some sample source code.

Comment: I think that the best answer is that there are not quick and easy solutions that will take you from a Java Object (in a Java program) to a C struct (in a C program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data serialisation is the buzz word here.

For a quiet impressive list of techniques you might like to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Comment: Thanks! Just fixed this ... @alex